# All IP Addresses arent accessible to Router Config Page

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\-REDACTED>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : -REDACTED
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 802.11n USB Wireless LAN Card
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : -REDACTED
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : -REDACTED
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : -REDACTED
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : -REDACTED
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.21(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : -REDACTED
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : -REDACTED
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : -REDACTED
                                       10.0.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 301993747
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : -REDACTED

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : -REDACTED
                                       208.67.222.222
                                       208.67.220.220
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : -REDACTED
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{-REDACTED}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : -REDACTED
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Reusable ISATAP Interface {-REDACTED}:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : -REDACTED
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

(redacted some useless/personal/physical addresses)

Im attempting to reach my Router Config page (To do some port forwarding, and I need to configure a specific thing)

I dont have access to the physical router, but i have full admin WIRELESS access to it.

the weird thing, is that the router's connection address: 10.0.1.1 (IPv4 Default Gateway) isnt working.

It simply gives me a "page not found" error. Ive attempted EVERY other IP address thats not redacted in that hatebin page above... yet nothing connects... Why is that??

Comment: Can you ping the router? Has the person who manages the router changed any settings?

Comment: Check router's settings - the acces to its interface from WLAN segment can be disabled.

Comment: @Akina I dont know how to do that, and I dont have access to the router IRL

Comment: @Kinnectus Im unsure what you mean. Also my router never really changes.

Comment: If you don't have physical access to the router and you can't access the URL over wireless then your options are limited. Has anyone else got admin access to the router? They may have disabled the ability to access the router's login page over wireless (@Akina's comment). Can you ping the router? Can you get to the router's login page using another device (your phone, for example)? Can another device ping the router? There's lots of basic troubleshooting that can be done, but you haven't documented this on here so we'll assume you don't know what else to try...

Comment: @Kinnectus Well, Unfortunately my parents dont trust me with our router, ive proven myself to have a computer without any restrictions and even write my own programs. But they have yet to trust me with access to our source of wireless data. I guess i can understand why (The first thing I ever asked them with our router was to give me full access so I could port forward my game to let "random people" join from anywhere)

Comment: "Unfortunately my parents dont trust me with our router" we can't help you with that.